# Accessing Elements or Controls in a UWP ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a XAML `UserControl` that inherits from the CalendarView element. In the CalendarViewItemStyle, I have edited the ControlTemplate to hold a Grid and a TextBox.

```
<Style x:Name="CalDayStyle"
           TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="cTemp">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="CalDayStack"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tasksPres"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am trying to access the TextBox but to no avail, using FindName(). What do I do.

Comment: I don't think you can get the TextBlock data just like that, You need to create a `DependancyObject` and then Bind that to `TextBlock` Text so that you can get that value from `UserControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FindName cannot find names that are defined in applied templates. To find items in applied templates, use VisualTreeHelper.GetChild to get the applied template root object. Then you can call FindName on that root object, and you will be searching the XAML namescope of the template rather than the greater page.

If you want to get the `TextBlock` in your `Style`, you should be able touse the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243038) to get it.

For examole:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    texts = new List<TextBlock>();
}

private List<TextBlock> texts;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<TextBlock> textBlocks = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(Mycontrol);
    foreach (var textBlock in textBlocks)
    {
        if (textBlock.Name == "tasksPres")
        {
            texts.Add(textBlock);
        }
    }
    foreach (var item in texts)
    {
        item.Text = "11111111111";
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your comments you talk about using FindName on the root child of the template, but then in the sample code you do something quite different.